# Heegaard genus and ranks of fundamental groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, fundamental-groups, low-dimensional-topology

I found an interesting conjecture in the paper "Hyperbolic volume, Heegaard genus and ranks of groups" by Peter B. Shalen.

It says that if $M$ is a compact, orientable, hyperbolic 3-manifold, then the rank of $\pi_1(M)$ is equal to the Heegard genus of $M$.

How open is this conjecture? Do you know how to prove it or can you find a counterexample?

Comment: apparently it is been proven false https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.6302

Comment: Thank you a lot!